# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5

Tags: php, html

Here is my php code,i searched about the solution but even after adding `var_dump($request);` i got the same Notice<`Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5`>.

index.php

```
<?php 
$rd = dirname(__FILE__);
$request[]='';
var_dump($request);
if ($request[1] == '')
  {
        $request[1] = 'header';
    include($rd.'/php_includes/'.$request[1].'.php');
  }


if ($request[0] == '')
  {
    $request[0] = 'index';
    include($rd.'/php_includes/'.$request[0].'.php');
  }

?>
```

Could you please Help me out with this?

Comment: did you mean $request[1]='';

Comment: Just curious, what does `$request[]='';` mean?

Comment: @EisaAdil it adds the value to the next available index number in the array.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem According to a test I just conducted, it does not issue a notice.

Comment: @NickCoons: my... you're right. It used to produce notices, I'm sure, because I've had to spend ages fixing code that never declared arrays... just tried with error_reporting(-1) and indeed, no notices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, `$request` doesn't exist.  You add one element with `$request=[]''`, so now you have `$request[0]` set.  Shortly thereafter, you reference `$request[1]` without it being first defined.  There is no `$request[1]`, which is why you're getting this notice.

Your line that checks to see if it has a value, and throws the notice because it's not set, is this one:

```
if ($request[1] == '')
```

If you want to check to see if it's empty without throwing a notice, use this:

```
if (empty($request[1]))
```

This will return `TRUE` if `$request[1]` is not set, is set to `NULL`, empty, or 0; so it should accomplish what you're trying to do without throwing a notice.

Comment: `empty` has a couple of gotcha's (owing to the wacky truth table of PHP), better use `isset($request[1])`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what these "gotcha's" are? I've used this method many times without issue. Also, `isset($request[1])` and `empty($request[1])` will not return the same results (looking at the context of the OP's post, the `isset()` method looks like it will not provide the correct results.

Comment: [There's a definitive guide](http://kunststube.net/isset/) which discusses the differences and caveats of `empty`

Comment: Thanks for posting as it was an interesting read, but there's nothing there that indicates that `empty()` is inappropriate for the OP's question (other than the fact that there should be no question as to the existence of the variable since it is entirely contained within the script and not provided externally, though that's a separate issue).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because youare calling $request[1] when it is not set.
If you want $request to be declared as an empty array do it like:

```
$request = array();
```

if you want to check if it is set or empty

```
if (!isset($request[1]) || empty($request[1]))
{
    //your code here in case of not existing or being empty
}

$request[] = ''; // adds a value to the next key - they are autogenerated from 0 as int 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 and so on, if you don't declare them otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` ORDER BY id DESC";
    $statement = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    // if(count($data)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement))
        {
            echo $row[1];
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30563028)